# Hp probook 450 G7 not entering bios menu

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I have a probook 450 G7 that I was using with Windows 11 installed but wanted to downgrade to Windows 10 due to windows software compatibility.

I did the go back.. after too many restart my laptop started to just show the HPp logo and restarting again and again.

I tried entering bios and even resetting bios with win+B but it couldn't, replaced the ram and HDD, but it kept just booting showing HP logo and restarting.

I can't enter the bios menu, tried all keys.

Can it be associated with a hardware issue?

Comment: The machine is reasonably new (Windows 11). Is it still under warranty (get it serviced). Make sure from HP it will run Windows 10.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @john it's not  a new one and didn't come with windows 11 pre installed i updated it. I was using it for quite some time

Comment: Try: Rebuilding the computer (fresh install) and then installing compatible software and watch for software errors.

Comment: Can't enter boot menu neither bios setup just showing that it wants to enter boot menu then restarting.

Comment: Get an HP Recovery USB and set it up that way.

Comment: There is no other key to use than F10. Try shutting *completely* by holding down the power button for ~10 seconds while it tries to boot. Then, with power off, hold down F!0 and keep it depressed while powering on again. https://www.infofuge.com/hp-probook-bios-key-to-enter-into-bios/ You can also try repeatedly clicking F10, but I have not found that helpful.